# Custom Time Marshall Unmarshall

Tags: json, go, time, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a `MysqlTime` struct with it's own marshall and unmarshall.

```
type MysqlTime struct {
    time.Time
}

const MYSQL_TIME_FORMAT = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"

func (t *MysqlTime) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    s := strings.Trim(string(b), `\`)
    if s == "null" {
        t.Time = time.Time{}
        return
    }
    t.Time, err = time.Parse(MYSQL_TIME_FORMAT, s)
    return
}

func (t *MysqlTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if t.Time.UnixNano() == nilTime {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`"%s"`, t.Time.Format(MYSQL_TIME_FORMAT))), nil
}

var nilTime = (time.Time{}).UnixNano()

func (t *MysqlTime) IsSet() bool {
    return t.UnixNano() != nilTime
}
```

Now I wish to use it...

```
type Foo struct {
    Time *MysqlTime
}

func main() {

    now := MysqlTime(time.Now())

    foo := Foo{}
    foo.Time = &now
}
```

Error:

```
cannot convert now (type time.Time) to type helpers.MysqlTime
cannot take the address of helpers.MysqlTime(now)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing this:

```
now := MysqlTime(time.Now())
```

It tries to convert a `Time` to your `MysqlTime` type (which throws an error).

Did you mean to actually initialize the inner `Time` attribute, like so?

```
now := MysqlTime{time.Now()}
```